# Improving search function

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a search btxtbox with button to search for data in the Gridview. I'm not using any code behind page but I'm using the select command and Where function and linking them to the parameters

How can I make the Gridview appear before making the search? 
I mean before typing and clicking on search for the data to appear.

aspx page :

```
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM;ALLSTAFF; WHERE (USER_NAME; = :USER_NAME)">
    <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" Name="USER_NAME" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
   </SelectParameters>
```

Comment: What are all these semicolons doing in your query?

Comment: it is generated automatically anytime I work with Oracle database,but it has no impact on my search function.